# React router does not reload component if same element is used for two paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following two paths set up

```
<Route path="bookings/:bookingnumber" element={<Bookings />} />
<Route path="bookings" element={<Bookings />} />
```

In `Bookings` component I have conditional code written to check if a parameter `:bookingnumber` is passed, and then it only shows results relevant to that booking number.
Otherwise, if no parameter is passed, it shows all the results for all the bookings.

I am using `Outlet` to display these components in the main area, and the two paths can be chosen from a sidebar.

Let's say I have `10 results` if I go to `/bookings`, and `2 results` if I go to `/bookings/123`.

However, if I go to `/bookings/123` first and then to `/bookings` it keeps on showing only `2 results` (the component does not reload, however I can see the URL changing in the browser)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Issue

```
<Route path="bookings" element={<Bookings />} />
<Route path="bookings/:bookingnumber" element={<Bookings />} />
```

With the same component rendered on more than 1 route, if you navigate from one route to another for the same routes component, the routed component remains mounted.

Example: If navigating from `"/bookings"` to `"/bookings/123"`, or `"/bookings/123"` to `"/bookings"`, or `"/bookings/123"` to `"/bookings/456"` the `Bookings` component remains mounted. If you've any logic that depends on the `bookingnumber` route path parameter then the `Bookings` component needs to handle this in a `useEffect` hook with a proper dependency on the `bookingnumber` param.

## Solution

Use a `useEffect` hook to "listen" for changes to the `bookingnumber` param value.

Example:

```
const Bookings = () => {
  const { bookingnumber } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // initial render or booking number value updated
    // run logic depending on bookingnumber value to update "results"
    ... 
  }, [bookingnumber]);

  ...
};
```

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling too with this issue, the solution is to add the `key` prop, which is used by react to understand when 2 components are different (otherwise it assumes they're the same and they will not be re-rendered).

Hence the solution in your case may look like:

`<Route key={'single'} path="bookings/:bookingnumber" element={<Bookings />} />`

`<Route key={'all'} path="bookings" element={<Bookings />} />`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path="bookings" element={<BookingList />}>
  <Route path=":bookingnumber" element={<ViewBooking />} />
</Route>
```

make two pages, first one will show all list of bookings and second one will show ID data

Comment: I am getting the same result even with this.

Comment: Then you can make two pages first will show all list of booking after pass ID then show second page.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I believe you are using `react-router-dom v6`, in this case you can wrap the child routes inside your main path route. And then give them the `index(true|false)` attribute to make sure the router understand if it is the exact index page or should render a page based on params.

Note: I copied the example from above, and added some lines to fix it!

```js
<Route path="bookings">
  <Route index={false} path=":bookingnumber" element={<ViewBooking />} />
  <Route index={true} element={<BookingList />} />
</Route>
```

**UPDATE:**
You can handle a single component route with `useParams` hook.

Here what you're routing file should look like:

```js
<Route path="bookings">
  <Route index={false} path=":bookingnumber" element={<ViewBooking />} />
  <Route index={true} element={<BookingList />} />
</Route>
```

And this is what your component should look like:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {

  const { bookingnumber } = useParams()
  
  // if the path doesn't include the booking number then we should just render a normal page
  if( !bookingnumber ) {
    return <h1>This is a simple page</h1>
  }
  
  
  // if the page path does include the booking number then we can fetch data and return another result
  // example you can fetch data based on this number
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const req = await fetch(`https://629c770de9358232f75b55dc.mockapi.io/api/v1/users/${bookingnumber}`)
      const data = await req.json()
      setUsername(data.name)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [username])

  return (
    <h1>Welcome mr.{username}</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: But will this work for my case? Since, I am using a single component (just <Bookings/>) for both the routes.

Comment: My react router dom version: "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"

Comment: I tried your approach with my single component. Still getting the same result.

Comment: @Saif Please check the updates i've made to the answer!